# Laravel 5.4 - Code for javascript screensaver in blade not running but have no error in console?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, screensaver

I have here a blade page on laravel 5.4  that allows users to input survey responses. The system should show a screensaver after being idle for a certain time ie. idle is 5mins. but the screensaver should disappear when somebody interact with the page. but the codes did not function. I've check the console but it has no error in google chrome. (newbie in javascript)

```
@php
    use App\Bus;
    use App\Bgcroute;
    use App\Surveyquestion;
    use App\User;
    use Controller\UserController;
@endphp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BGC Bus Survey Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/user.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Pretty-Footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Pretty-Header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Hero-Technology.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js-screensaver/screensaver.css">

    <script src="js-screensaver/screensaver.js"></script>
    <script src="sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script src="sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert2.min.js">
    <style type="text/css">
    .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 1 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 0;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    min-height: 55px;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  .img-logo{
    width: 75px;
    height: 60px;
  }

  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #53DFF0;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .nav-bar-nav li a {
    color: #D5D5D5;
  }
        .avatar{
        border-radius: 100%;
        max-width: 100px;
        clip: rect(10px,60px,50px,10px);

        }    

    .startScreenSaver({
        timeout: 5000,
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        exitTimeout: 1000,
    }); 
    </style>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                     <form action="{{route('logout')}}" method="post">
{!!csrf_field()!!} 
@if(!empty(Auth::user()->image))
              <img src="{{ Auth::user()->image  }}" class="avatar" alt="" width="60" height="60">
            @else
              <img src={{ url('uploads/avatar.png') }} class="avatar" alt="" width="60" height="60">
            @endif 
<b>Your Driver of the Day, {{ Auth::user()->name  }}</b>            
<button class="btn btn-danger">Log out</button>

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Route/Bus Details
</button>

</form>

        </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select Your Desire Route</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

<div class="modal-body">

<form action="{{ route('surveysubmit') }}" >

<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Select Bus</h4>
    <select onchange="$('#busid').val(this.value);" class="form-control" >
        @php
        $display=''; $initbusid = '';
         $buses = Bus::where(['archive'=>1])->orderBy('id')->get(['id','busplate']);
        foreach($buses as $bus){
            if(empty($initbusid)){$initbusid=$bus->id;}
        $display .= '<option value='.$bus->id.'>'.$bus->busplate.'</option>';
        }
        echo $display;
        @endphp
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Select Route</h4>
        <select onchange="$('#routeid').val(this.value);" class="form-control" >
        @php
        $display2=''; $initrouteid = '';
          $bgcroutes = Bgcroute::where(['routeloc'=>1,'archive'=>1])->orderBy('id')->get(['id','bgcbusroute']);
        foreach($bgcroutes as $bgcroute){
             if(empty($initrouteid)){$initrouteid=$bgcroute->id;}
        $display2 .= '<option value='.$bgcroute->id.'>'.$bgcroute->bgcbusroute.'</option>';
        }
        echo $display2;
        @endphp
    </select>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Start Survey</button>
</form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@php
   $questions =  Surveyquestion::where('status',1)->get(['squestions','id'])->first();
@endphp

    <section class="testimonials"></section>
    <div class="jumbotron visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block hero-technology">
        <h2 class="bg-success hero-title">{{ $questions->squestions }}</h2>
        <p class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block visible-xs-inline visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline visible-xs-inline-block visible-sm-inline-block visible-md-inline-block visible-lg-inline-block hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hero-subtitle">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>
        <p class="text-primary bg-warning">Help Us Serve You Better</p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="text-center bg-primary">Rate us. Choose a smiley that Corresponds to your riding experience</p>
        <div>

            <input type="hidden" name="driverid" id="driverid" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="busid" id="busid" value="{{ $initbusid }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="routeid" id="routeid" value="{{ $initrouteid }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="questionid"  id="questionid" value="{{ $questions->id }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="responseid" id="responseid"/>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="info visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block visible-xs-inline visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline visible-xs-inline-block">
                          <img class="img-rounded" src="assets/img/person-clipart-silhouette-blue-14518-blue-man-design.png" height="100">
                           <a href="#" onclick="$('#responseid').val('1');surveyvote();">   <img src="assets/img/inlove.gif" height="70" id="loveid"> </a>
                            <a href="#" onclick="$('#responseid').val('2');surveyvote();"> <img src="assets/img/like.gif" height="90" id="likeid"></a>
                            <a href="#" onclick="$('#responseid').val('3');surveyvote();"> <img src="assets/img/facepalm.gif" height="70" id="faceid"> </a>
                            <a href="#" onclick="$('#responseid').val('4');surveyvote();"> <img src="assets/img/cry.gif" height="70" id="cryid"> </a> 
                        </th>
                        <th
                        class="danger visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block visible-xs-inline visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline visible-xs-inline-block">
                        <img class="img-rounded" src="assets/img/pink-female-symbol-190136.png" width="40" height="100">
                        <a href="#" onclick="$('#responseid').val('5');surveyvote();"> <img src="assets/img/inlove.gif" height="70" id="loveid2"> </a>
                        <a href="#" onclick="$('#responseid').val('6');surveyvote();"> <img src="assets/img/like.gif" height="90" id="likeid2"> </a>
                        <a href="#" onclick="$('#responseid').val('7');surveyvote();"> <img src="assets/img/facepalm.gif" height="70" id="faceid2"> </a>
                        <a href="#" onclick="$('#responseid').val('8');surveyvote();"> <img src="assets/img/cry.gif" height="70" id="cryid2"> </a>
                        </th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                </tbody>
                <caption> </caption>
            </table>

        </div>
        <p>For Comments/Feedback Email us at bgc@bgc.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e){

        });

          function surveyvote(){
               driverid = $('#driverid').val();
               busid = $('#busid').val();
               routeid = $('#routeid').val();
               questionid = $('#questionid').val();
               responseid =  $('#responseid').val();
                $.ajax({
                    "type":"get",
                    "url": "{{ route('surveyvoting')  }}",
                    "data": '&driverid='+driverid+'&busid='+busid+'&routeid='+routeid+'&questionid='+questionid+'&responseid='+responseid,
                    "success":function(result){
                        // Do something you want!

                    swal({
                      title: 'Thank You!',
                      //text: 'I will close in 3 seconds.',
                      timer: 1000,
                      onOpen: () => {
                        swal.showLoading()
                      }
                    }).then((result) => {
                      if (
                        // Read more about handling dismissals
                        result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.timer
                      ) {
                        console.log('I was closed by the timer')
                      }
                    })
                    }
                });


            }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

         var screenSaver = {};


function startScreenSaver(options) {

  //* attach event listeners to exit screensaver
  attachScreenSaverEventListeners();

  if(!screenSaver.initiated) {

    //* set screensaver options
    screenSaver.options = {

       timeout: options.timeout || 5000, //* default timer to start screensaver is 10 minutes

        width: options.width || 25,   //* default width is 25rem

        height: options.height || 25, //* default height is 25rem

        exitTimeout: options.exitTimeout || null, //* default timer to exit screensaver is disabled

    }

    //* create elements
    var overlay = document.createElement("div");

    overlay.setAttribute('class', 'screensaver-overlay');

    document.body.appendChild(overlay);

    var createBadge = document.createElement("div");

    createBadge.setAttribute('id', 'saver-badge');

    document.body.appendChild(createBadge);

    createBadge.style.width = screenSaver.options.width + 'rem';

     createBadge.style.height = screenSaver.options.height + 'rem';

  }

  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove('screensaver');

  screenSaver.initiated = true;

  screenSaver.setTimeoutValue = screenSaver.options.timeout; 

  screenSaver.setTimeoutExit = screenSaver.options.timeoutExit; 

  screenSaver.setTimeout = null; //* clear timeout

  screenSaver.inProgress = false;

  screenSaver.timerStarted = false;

  clearTimeout(screenSaver.setTimeout);

  screenSaver.setTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add('screensaver');

      screenSaver.inProgress = true;

      var saverBadge = document.getElementById("saver-badge");

      clearInterval(screenSaver.setInterval); //* clear badge display interval

      screenSaver.setInterval = null;

      //* get dimensions in em
      var windowHeight = window.outerHeight / parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

      var windowWidth = window.outerWidth / parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

      screenSaver.setInterval = setInterval(function() {

        if (screenSaver.inProgress === true) {

          saverBadge.classList.remove('visible');

          setTimeout(function() {

            saverBadge.offsetWidth = saverBadge.offsetWidth;

            saverBadge.classList.add('visible');

          },1);

          var saverTopValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * windowHeight) - screenSaver.options.width;

          var saverLeftValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * windowWidth) - screenSaver.options.height;

          if (saverTopValue <= 0) { //* make sure the badge doesn't go off the screen

            saverTopValue = saverTopValue + 15;

          }

          if (saverLeftValue <= 0) {

            saverLeftValue = saverLeftValue + 15;

          }

          saverBadge.style.top = saverTopValue + 'rem';

          saverBadge.style.left = saverLeftValue + 'rem';

          if(screenSaver.timerStarted === false && screenSaver.options.exitTimeout != null) {

            startScreenSaverTimer();

          }
        }
      }, 6000);

    }, screenSaver.setTimeoutValue);
}

function startScreenSaverTimer() {

  screenSaver.timerStarted = true;

  setTimeout(function() {

    stopScreenSaver();

  }, screenSaver.setTimeoutExit);

}

function stopScreenSaver() {

  startScreenSaver();

  clearInterval(screenSaver.setInterval);

  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove('screensaver');

  screenSaver.timerStarted = false;

}

function attachScreenSaverEventListeners() {

  var events = ['touchstart', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'touchmove', 'keypress', 'scroll'];

  var resetScreenSaver = function(e) {

    if (screenSaver.inProgress) {

      e.stopPropagation();

      e.preventDefault();

    }

    clearTimeout(screenSaver.setTimeout);

    clearInterval(screenSaver.setInterval);

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove('screensaver');

    startScreenSaver();

  }

  var checkClick = function(e) {

    if (screenSaver.inProgress) {

      startScreenSaver();

    }

  }

  var bindEvents = function(eventName) {

    document.addEventListener(eventName, screenSaver.initialize);

    //* bind click as fallback for touchstart and mousedown
    document.addEventListener('click', checkClick);

  }

  var unbindEvents = function(eventName) {

    document.removeEventListener(eventName, screenSaver.initialize);

  }

}    

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is the related files that I think that is related on the script or the javascript

css file screensaver.css

```
body.screensaver #saver-badge {
        opacity: 0;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12,Color='#444')";
        filter: url(#drop-shadow);
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
        filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
        background: url(../img/vwd.png) center;
        background-size: contain;
        z-index: 1001;
}

 body.screensaver #saver-badge.visible {
  -webkit-animation: fadeBadge 6s; 
  -moz-animation:    fadeBadge 6s; 
  -o-animation:      fadeBadge 6s; 
  animation:         fadeBadge 6s; 
  opacity: 1;
}

body.screensaver .screensaver-overlay {
  background: #000;
  opacity: .5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#saver-badge {
  display: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeBadge {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeBadge {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeBadge {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeBadge {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

js file
screensaver.js

```
var screenSaver = {};


function startScreenSaver(options) {

  //* attach event listeners to exit screensaver
  attachScreenSaverEventListeners();

  if(!screenSaver.initiated) {

    //* set screensaver options
    screenSaver.options = {

       timeout: options.timeout || 60000, //* default timer to start screensaver is 10 minutes

        width: options.width || 25,   //* default width is 25rem

        height: options.height || 25, //* default height is 25rem

        exitTimeout: options.exitTimeout || null, //* default timer to exit screensaver is disabled

    }

    //* create elements
    var overlay = document.createElement("div");

    overlay.setAttribute('class', 'screensaver-overlay');

    document.body.appendChild(overlay);

    var createBadge = document.createElement("div");

    createBadge.setAttribute('id', 'saver-badge');

    document.body.appendChild(createBadge);

    createBadge.style.width = screenSaver.options.width + 'rem';

     createBadge.style.height = screenSaver.options.height + 'rem';

  }

  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove('screensaver');

  screenSaver.initiated = true;

  screenSaver.setTimeoutValue = screenSaver.options.timeout; 

  screenSaver.setTimeoutExit = screenSaver.options.timeoutExit; 

  screenSaver.setTimeout = null; //* clear timeout

  screenSaver.inProgress = false;

  screenSaver.timerStarted = false;

  clearTimeout(screenSaver.setTimeout);

  screenSaver.setTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add('screensaver');

      screenSaver.inProgress = true;

      var saverBadge = document.getElementById("saver-badge");

      clearInterval(screenSaver.setInterval); //* clear badge display interval

      screenSaver.setInterval = null;

      //* get dimensions in em
      var windowHeight = window.outerHeight / parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

      var windowWidth = window.outerWidth / parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

      screenSaver.setInterval = setInterval(function() {

        if (screenSaver.inProgress === true) {

          saverBadge.classList.remove('visible');

          setTimeout(function() {

            saverBadge.offsetWidth = saverBadge.offsetWidth;

            saverBadge.classList.add('visible');

          },1);

          var saverTopValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * windowHeight) - screenSaver.options.width;

          var saverLeftValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * windowWidth) - screenSaver.options.height;

          if (saverTopValue <= 0) { //* make sure the badge doesn't go off the screen

            saverTopValue = saverTopValue + 15;

          }

          if (saverLeftValue <= 0) {

            saverLeftValue = saverLeftValue + 15;

          }

          saverBadge.style.top = saverTopValue + 'rem';

          saverBadge.style.left = saverLeftValue + 'rem';

          if(screenSaver.timerStarted === false && screenSaver.options.exitTimeout != null) {

            startScreenSaverTimer();

          }
        }
      }, 6000);

    }, screenSaver.setTimeoutValue);
}

function startScreenSaverTimer() {

  screenSaver.timerStarted = true;

  setTimeout(function() {

    stopScreenSaver();

  }, screenSaver.setTimeoutExit);

}

function stopScreenSaver() {

  startScreenSaver();

  clearInterval(screenSaver.setInterval);

  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove('screensaver');

  screenSaver.timerStarted = false;

}

function attachScreenSaverEventListeners() {

  var events = ['touchstart', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'touchmove', 'keypress', 'scroll'];

  var resetScreenSaver = function(e) {

    if (screenSaver.inProgress) {

      e.stopPropagation();

      e.preventDefault();

    }

    clearTimeout(screenSaver.setTimeout);

    clearInterval(screenSaver.setInterval);

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove('screensaver');

    startScreenSaver();

  }

  var checkClick = function(e) {

    if (screenSaver.inProgress) {

      startScreenSaver();

    }

  }

  var bindEvents = function(eventName) {

    document.addEventListener(eventName, screenSaver.initialize);

    //* bind click as fallback for touchstart and mousedown
    document.addEventListener('click', checkClick);

  }

  var unbindEvents = function(eventName) {

    document.removeEventListener(eventName, screenSaver.initialize);

  }

  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {

    bindEvents(events[i]);

  }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear you've called the `startScreenSaver ` function to get the screensaver timeout and listeners set up.

Comment: where could I put that? thanks.